# POSTing after user chooses from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out how to POST the option the user chooses from the drop down list that's named "Drop".

Whichever option the user chooses when they click submit, I want it to POST the drop down list's value to something.php

So for example if the user chooses Monthly or Hourly, it should post "Hourly" or "Monthly" to something.php

How can this be done?

http://pastebin.com/Lr4a8KMq

```
<select id="mySelect" name="Drop" class="testingStyles">
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>Week</option>
    <option>Day</option>
    <option>Hour</option>
</select>
<input type="button" class="formbutton" onclick="getIndex()" value="Alert index of selected option">
<br/>
<br/>
<form Method ="POST" action="something.php">
    <div id="numbers">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" style="width: 75px; border: 1px solid gray" class="formbutton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is a little verbose. Could you filter out what exactly is appropriate for your question please?

Comment: Why was this closed? It is answerable and my answer is probably spot-on. This is a very common beginner's mistake. And since the user is new to SO, I would say it's a very common beginner's mistake not to post a clearer question too. I think that yes, it can be improved a lot, but no, it should not be closed.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help, haha it took me hours of frustration but this will teach a good lesson

Comment: Vote to reopen - The question and Simeon's request seem reasonable

Comment: +1 for reopening. There is nothing wrong with this question in principle.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with re-opening once the question is fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the drop-down is not part of the `<form>` element. Move the form's start tag up to include the drop-down.

Move `<form  Method="POST" action="something.php">` to above the `<select>` tag.

Comment: thanks I was playing around n I figuered that out, It was such a newbie mistake